# ASP.NET C# How do I pass canvas image to controller as Bitmap

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following javascript that sends the `canvas` image on my `View` to the controller in the form of a string. But I would like to convert the string into a `Bitmap` format. How can I do so?

```
    document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Attendance/Decode",
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Done, Picture Sent.");
        }
    });

});
```

Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult Decode(string imageData)
{
   //Convert imageData to Bitmap
}
```

Is there any other way to send the `canvas` image as a `Bitmap` to the controller?

Answer (score 3):

If you're receiving a URI or Base64, you can use **[BitmapImage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx)** to convert it to bitmap.

Uri:

```
 BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(url);
```

[Base64String:](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Converting-Base64-strings-8808c305)

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Close();
memoryStream = null;
byteBuffer = null;
```

Hope it helps!